# Html link color Bug

Tags: html

Hey so I've made these `links` and they are for some reason they are purple

```
<a href="http://www.setupstudie.dk/kontakt.php"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"<font face="arial" size="4" color="#000000"><B>Contact</B></a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use <font> tag, it doesn't work in modern browsers, and anyways it's pointless here

Comment: oof! Don't use <font> tag again!

Comment: You're also missing a closing angle bracket '>' between the Style attribute and the beginning of the Font element. The Font element should wrap other elements, so you should have a close tag after the </B>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug.

It's default behaviour. Visited links (by default, are purple). You can disable it by CSS:

```
a:visited{
color:#000;
}
```

This would show visited links as black.

Also, `<a href="http://www.setupstudie.dk/kontakt.php"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"<font face="arial" size="4" color="#000000"><B>Contact</B></a>` is a horrible way of styling text. You're not even closing the tag.

Comment: Where do i put the a:visited{
color:#000;
} @Christian

Comment: I'd recommend a basic html tutorial. http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/the_basics_of_html

Comment: In your stylesheet. @Victordamidget

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the tip, didn't know that. I'll remove the comment

Comment: @T3H40 There's nothing wrong with w3schools, as long as you don't blindly believe what's written in there ;). It can be used as a reference, but not in this case where OP doesn't have any idea of what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

They are purple, because you already visited them. You can change this color using the CSS `:visited` selector like so:

```
a:visited
{
  color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp
For links there are four states you want to style. link, visited, hover, and active.

Comment: That is all about your point of view. I personally think w3schools is a good source to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your link by using CSS

```
a { color: blue; }
```

or detailed your link color like

```
a:link - default link style
a:hover - link style while mouse on the link
a:active - link style while mouse click on the link (active this link)
a:visited - link style for which have already visited ever
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard `link` selectors and its default colors are:

`a:link` — defines the style for normal unvisited links. Default color: blue

`a:visited` — defines the style for visited links. Default color: purple;

`a:active` — defines the style for active links; links become active once you click on them. Default color: red;

`a:hover` — defines the style for hovered links; links hover when the mouse moves over it.

The reason for the purple color is, it is visited link. It is not bug, it is default behavioural. If you haven't configured the  default link properties, then HTML link element uses its own default color.

You can also customize link color by editing in your CSS file.

```
a {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
   color: purple;
}

a:active {
   color: red;
}
```